# Use of future reserved keywords in older standards

Tags: javascript

[According to the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Future_reserved_keywords), there's a number of words that were reserved for future use *only* in older versions of the standard (specifically ECMAScript 1 till 3).

If I understand correctly, this means that they are no longer reserved. And indeed, [they do not appear in the list of reserved words for ECMAScript 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1) (there was no EMCAScript 4).

So is there any reason not to use one of these previously reserved words in a modern JavaScript application? For example, I've found that words like `char`, `byte`, or `int` can be useful identifiers.

Comment: I don't think `int` is a good descriptive name for a variable

Comment: It's not descriptive, Bergi, but sometimes code is so general purpose that there is no descriptive names. The kind of code where you would usually use single variable names. Except this does marginally better by naming the type (or expected type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is there any reason not to use one of these previously reserved words in a modern JavaScript application?

Not really. Except that for some reason you had to support one the old - really old - browsers which use ES3.